# Angular Datatable - when the component is rendered for the first time I'm not getting any data

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

I am facing a really hard time working with the angular data table, I'm using ajax to get data from the API the problem is when the component is rendered for the first time I'm not getting any data after this if I click on the column to order the data it works well

I am initializing the dtOptions in the ngOnInit Method so I expected to get the data when the component is rendered for the first time

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n846Z.png)

after I click on a column to order the data or I try to use the search bar
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSt3O.png)

I'm getting this error in the console

```
main.ts:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Jb (node_modules\datatables.net\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js:40:238)
    at Aa (node_modules\datatables.net\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js:62:175)
    at f (node_modules\datatables.net\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js:111:104)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (node_modules\datatables.net\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js:111:157)
    at Function.each (node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:385:1)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:207:1)
    at jQuery.fn.init.u [as dataTable] (node_modules\datatables.net\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js:101:182)
    at l.fn.DataTable (node_modules\datatables.net\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js:191:467)
    at angular-datatables.directive.js:80:58
    at timer (zone.js:2405:41)
```

Environment:

- NodeJS version: 18.0.0
- Angular version: 14.1.0
- Angular CLI version: 14.1.0
- jQuery version: 3.6.1
- DataTables version: ^14.0.0
- angular-datatables version: ^14.0.0

//ngOnInit

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const me = this;
 // get language
 this.langServiceSupscribtion = this.sharedService.lang.subscribe((l) => {
  this.lang = l;
});

this.dtOptions = {
  paging: true,
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  autoWidth: true,
  serverSide: true,
  searching: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback, settings) => {
    console.log(dataTablesParameters);
    dataTablesParameters.searchCriteria = me._searchCriteria;
    me.transactionService
      .getAllTransactionsFunctional(dataTablesParameters)
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        if (resp['succeeded']) {
          me.transactionsList = resp['data'];
          console.log(me.transactionsList);
          callback({
            recordsTotal: resp['recordsTotal'],
            recordsFiltered: resp['recordsFiltered'],
            data: [],
          });
        } else {
          console.log("resp['errors']");
        }
      });
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'transactionType' },
    { data: 'radionuclideName' },
    { data: 'radioActivity' },
    { data: 'createdOn' },
    { data: 'facilityEn' },
    { data: 'licenseNumber' },
    { data: 'permitNumber' },
    { data: 'manufacturerSerialNo' },
    { data: 'sourceStatus' },
    { data: null },
  ],
};
```

}

// HTML

```
 <table
          datatable
          [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
          id="sourcesDataTable"
          class="table datatable table-responsive table-striped table-bordered row-border table-hover table-sm w-100 overflow-auto"
        >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.transactionType" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.radionuclide" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.radioactivity" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.transactionDate" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.facility" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.license" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.permit" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.manufacturerSerialNo" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th class="select-filter">
                {{ "landingPage.transactionStatus" | translate }}
              </th>
              <th>{{ "landingPage.view" | translate }}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody *ngIf="transactionsList?.length != 0">
            <tr *ngFor="let t of transactionsList">
              <td>{{ t.transactionType }}</td>
              <td>{{ t.radionuclideName }}</td>
              <td>{{ t.radioActivity }}</td>
              <td>{{ t.createdOn }}</td>
              <td>{{ t.facilityEn }}</td>
              <td>{{ t.licenseNumber }}</td>
              <td>{{ t.permitNumber }}</td>
              <td>{{ t.manufacturerSerialNo }}</td>
              <td>{{ t.sourceStatus }}</td>
              <td class="px-2">
                <button
                  class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm mx-1"
                  style="width: 100%"
                >
                  <fa-icon [icon]="faListDots"> </fa-icon>
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody *ngIf="transactionsList?.length == 0">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="10" class="no-data-available">
                {{ "no_data" | translate }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="transactionType"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{
                  'landingPage.transactionTypePlaceholder' | translate
                }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="radionuclide"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{
                  'landingPage.radionuclidePlaceholder' | translate
                }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="radioactivity"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{
                  'landingPage.radioactivityPlaceholder' | translate
                }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="transactionType"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{
                  'landingPage.transactionDatePlaceholder' | translate
                }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="transactionType"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{
                  'landingPage.facilityPlaceholder' | translate
                }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="transactionType"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{ 'landingPage.licensePlaceholder' | translate }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="transactionType"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{ 'landingPage.permitPlaceholder' | translate }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="transactionType"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{
                  'landingPage.manufacturerSerialNoPlaceholder' | translate
                }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th>
              <input
                class="search-input"
                name="transactionType"
                type="text"
                placeholder="{{
                  'landingPage.transactionStatusPlaceholder' | translate
                }}"
                style="width: 100%"
              />
            </th>
            <th></th>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Comment: Maybe add *ngIf="data" on your table

Comment: I didn't wrap the <th> tags in the footer inside the <tr> tag this was the problem